# Foreign Key that is defined in the hierachical Model

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a problem when defining a model in EF5. I want make the `ParentId` as a Foreign Key in the database but I'm getting an error:

> System.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmAssociationType: : Multiplicity conflicts with the referential constraint in Role 'Category_Parent_Target' in relationship 'Category_Parent'. Because all of the properties in the Dependent Role are non-nullable, multiplicity of the Principal Role must be '1'.

Here is my Model:

```
public class Category
{
    public Category()
    {
        this.Childs = new HashSet<Category>();
    }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Childs { get; set; } 
}
```

and

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
            .HasOptional(c => c.Parent)
            .WithMany(c => c.Childs)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.ParentId);
```

Comment: please format your code properly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a `Category` may or may not have a `Parent`, then the `ParentId` may or may not have a value.

So, make `ParentId` nullable:

```
public int? ParentId { get; set; }
```

Comment: i'm got another exception:
Sequence contains no elements

Comment: That's a separate issue. You will get it if you call `Single()` or `First()` on an empty collection.